# override default jquery impromptu width

Tags: jquery, impromptu

The following statement works fine with the exception that the width of the modal message is 400px, the default, instead of the desired 800px.

```
$.prompt(sFirstTest,{width:800});
```

The default of 400px is fine except for this one instance. The question is how do I best override the default for the one instance?

Comment: Try adding a "px" $.prompt(sFirstTest,{width:"800px"});

Comment: @xFortyFourx Thanks for the suggestion. I had actually tried that, and just to make sure I tried it again, but the result was the same: no error indication but no change either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me in the documentation all the time. In the Impromptu css there is:

```
div jqi {
    width:400px;
    .....
}
```

So I set up an alternate:

```
div jqiwide {
    width:800px;
    .....
}
```

Then the call to Impromptu for a wide instance is:

```
$.prompt(sFirstText,{prefix:'jqiwide'});
```

Comment: You have some typos: change `div jqi` to `div.jqi` and `div jqiwide` to `div.jqiwide`

Comment: @machineaddict, you are correct. I have edited the answer for future people reading this.

Answer (score 0):

And make sure to duplicate `impromptu.css` declarations with your new prefix, as they are not prepared for Id and classed with new prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
.customStyling div.jqi{
    width: 800px;
}

var dialogOptions = {
    buttons: [{...},{...}],
    classes: "customStyling"
};

$.prompt("msg", dialogOptions);
```